# How to import unknown number of images with drupal feeds from xml file?

Tags: feeds, 10

I am trying to import a gallery of images for a specific content type. The XML file looks like this:

```
 <img1>
 https://xml.....
 </img1>
 <img2>
 https://xml.....
 </img2>
 <img3>
 https://xml.....
 </img3>
 <img4>
 https://xml.....
 </img4>
 <img5>
 https://xml.....
 </img5>
```

The node has a different and unknown number of images.
I'm using QueryPath's XML parser to import the contents to the node, but I don't know how to import all the images. Some nodes have up to 50 images.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I don't understand specifically what you are asking or where it is that you are stuck.

Comment: When I mapping for a QueryPath XML source value, I use "img1" and parser imports image 1, but I don't know how many images they are for creating an exact number mappings.

Comment: I mean that the different nodes that need to be imported have different number of images and it's not clear where I should go with the mapping. The last can be img5 or img55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from QueryPath's XML parser to XPath, and used :

`//*[starts-with(local-name(), "img")]`

Thus, all images starting with 'img', regardless of the number after it, are imported without a problem.